# Can 2 computers work together on 1 python file?

Tags: python, pycharm

I recently made a discord bot just for fun. I made it on pycharm but if I close pycharm and/or my computer the bot goes offline. So to fix this i asked my friend if I could run it on his server. But the problem now is I have to ask permission to get into the file every 30 minutes or if i want to change anything. Is there an alternative to this or isn't there anything I can do about it.

main.py:

```
import bot

if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.run_discord_bot()
```

bot.py:

```
import discord

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'We have logged in as {client.user}')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('poep'):
        await message.channel.send(':poop:')

client.run('my token')
```

Tried searching on the internet but can't really find anything.

Comment: PyCharm is the development environment. What you are running is a script (a program) that is running the bot. That is independent of PyCharm. We more information to help. Show the file, tell us how you run it.

Comment: you can share code with github for example. to run the code, your friend just needs the script on the server. if you need authentication or something is a different issue.

Comment: @Gorgonzola i just use the 'run' button in pycharm

Comment: @Kane_js When you push the run button. The code is bellow. Show us that. We will show you how you can place it in your question so it is easy for other people to help. Snowman is on the right track

Comment: @Gorgonzola OP's problem is not how to run the file outside of PyCharm - they are running it on a server already. The unsolved problem is that the bot is offline when the computer is off

Comment: @Kane_js if you have scp/ssh access to the server, PyCharm supports uploading the file every time it's updated. However, to automatically restart you'll need to implement a watchdog, e.g. to terminate the script once the file is updated and configure a systemd service that will restart it

Comment: @Kane_js I didn't, probably Marat did. He is very good, don't worry about that. That's good, good job. Showing your code, writing a good question and explaining yourself helps you and everyone else.